# How do I remove the “likes” of others on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

There are people who abuse the liking system on Facebook by creating deliberately offensive account names and liking posts of others that they know would be offended by such names.

Is there a way to remove individual likes or even to disable the ability for people to like my posts at all?

Comment: Can you not block these people?

Comment: If they just 'like' your posts, without posting then no, they cannot be blocked. It is a loophole that facebook refuses to address.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to profiles with names like "your dad" likes this and so. If you find these names offensive, go to that profile and "Report" that account to Facebook.

That account will be removed by Facebook moderators.

Comment: Facebook tends to turn a blind eye to such behavior, no matter how many people report them, so of course that method has been  abandoned after many months of attempts, by myself and dozens of others.  

This is why I come here in the hope that there is a way to eliminate the source of the problem.